# Sencha Touch Infinite list variable heights image scroll to bottom

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have an infinite list with variable heights and images in most of them. Its basically a chat conversation list. I'm waiting until the store is fully loaded before showing the list. I'd also like to show the list only after it has completely scrolled to the bottom. The issue is that the list doesn't seem to reliably scrolling all the way to the bottom and instead stops midway. How can I reliably show the list only after it has completely scrolled to the bottom? Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply make a function like this:

```
scrollToBottom: function() {
    this.getMessageList().getScrollable().getScroller().scrollToEnd();
}
```

here `messageList` is reference for the chat-list and you should add the following code in the function where you are adding new messages in chat.

```
me.scrollToBottom();
setTimeout( function() {
    me.scrollToBottom();
}, 10);
setTimeout( function() {
    me.scrollToBottom();
}, 50);
```

Make sure the sequence. First append the above code and then add data to your store.
I hope this will help you. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Anand ! Unfortunately this is not very reliable. I have 2 delays each worth 500 ms, and yet it doesn't scroll to bottom consistently. Even when I add a record to the store, I time out and then scroll to bottom – and yet, many times the list scrolls down but the record never shows up. On scrolling up and down, the record renders okay. Thoughts?